How to bootstrap Angular application from Ember js
I want to bootstrap angular webapp from ember js and for that, we have imported angular bundle files into index html of ember js and trying to bootstrap angular by <app-root> </app-root> but its giving error  NG05104: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements in the ember app.

If you want to bootstrap the whole app, then I would create a web component out of it. There are certain limitations but I did it once for Angular 12 (if I am not mistaken) and it worked just fine. Here is an answer how to do it for Angular 16: Converting a complete Angular application into a WebComponent
